# D3.js radial text

Tags: d3.js

In d3.js how can a align text like in the figure ?

I have an arc and I want to place the text "radial" to this arc.
The origin is the black dot and the data of the arc is radius and [start(radians),end(radians)].

In advance, thanks!
[image: radial text]

the code (partial):

```
...
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(ras2)
        .startAngle(d.sa * Math.PI)
        .endAngle(d.sb * Math.PI);
   svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill","red");
...
```

Comment: Share your code and we can show you how to do it. Also, please remove those 3 meaningless tags.

Comment: Thanks in advance Gerardo, I added the relevant code above.